# JMH: don't take into account inner method time

Tags: java, benchmarking, microbenchmark, jmh

**I have:** Methods like this:

```
@GenerateMicroBenchmark
public static void calculateArraySummary(String[] args) {
    // create a random data set
    /* PROBLEM HERE: 
     * now I measure not only pool.invoke(finder) time,
     * but also generateRandomArray method time
     */
    final int[] array = generateRandomArray(1000000); 

    // submit the task to the pool
    final ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(4);
    final ArraySummator finder = new ArraySummator(array);
    System.out.println(pool.invoke(finder));
}

private static int[] generateRandomArray(int length) {
    final int[] array = new int[1000000];
    final Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = random.nextInt(100);
    }
    return array;
}
```

**Problem:** I don't want my program take into account time spent by `generateRandomArray` method.

**Questuin:** *How can I exclude `generateRandomArray` from jmh measurements?*

Comment: The trivial answer would be: by designing your methods so that the benchmarks apply to the entire method.  Provide the random array as an `@Measurement` if you can, or generate it in a setup method or static block if you can't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When in doubt, look through the JMH Samples. The effect you want is achieved by `@Setup` annotation over some fixture method, which will be run before the benchmark. The exact answer in JMH Samples is [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/75f8b23444f6/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_06_FixtureLevel.java).

Comment: Please add most revelant parts of linked resource into your answer, as of now, this is a link only answer, and so will be downwoted.

Comment: @jb I don't think SO should promote copy-pasting from the docs when the answer is *exactly* described by the docs. If you look for something to downvote, do that on the original question instead as if OP had not done his/her own homework.

Comment: There is a pedagogical value in silently pointing people to the docs which they have to read before using stuff. The case in question is trivial and exactly described by the docs. There is no controversy, no misunderstanding, just laziness on OPs part. There is no excuse, IMO, in reinforcing the laziness by embracing those kind of questions with thorough answers.

Comment: Even though I cannot but agree privately with the note on pedagogical value, Stack Overflow is a site catering to many more concerns beyond pedagogy. Specifically relevant here is the value of the answer to the general public. If pedagogical effect, directed personally at OP, is all that is desired, the avenue is 1. comment with the link, 2. vote to close.